# How to create android multitasking view?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I am actually trying to recreate this type of view, that can be seen when clicking on the right button of Android 6.0
But it doesn't look like a recyclerview, does someone know anything about it ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such questions, I always like to point people to the [Android Open Source Project](https://android.googlesource.com/). Looking around there, you can quickly stumble upon the 'Recents' implementation in the SystemUI package:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents?autodive=0%2F/

It's quite a complicated setup, but reading through it you will learn (and see) the exact implementation of the Recents system UI component, exactly as pictured in your above image. Start with the Recents.java than proceed around the RecentsActivity.java and see the views and the implementation for it. It's all custom and if you re-use their code (feel free), please note the license for using it!

Hope it helps!

Comment: PS knowing your way around in the Android source code can be your most useful skill and best weapon if you are an Android developer :) Cheers!

Comment: I lokked at the code but I couldn't find any function that would describe the way the view is built.

Comment: @Cornetto Well in that case, somebody else already did that job for you and simplified it here: https://github.com/ZieIony/MaterialRecents